# The iPhone app on device can connect and send file to another device via bluetooth which is running this app

Tags: ios, iphone, file, bluetooth

In my iPhone app, I want to connect and send file via Bluetooth to another device which is running the same app.
I googled many suggested like that: [use the CoreBluetooth](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741)
 with [example source code](https://github.com/orepereira/CoreBluetooth/tree/master/CBTutorial) Or [BluetoothManager](http://www.pocketmagic.net/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/)

But in the BluetoothManager, I don't see any method for sending/receiving data/file.
In the example code of CoreBluetooth, I try to install to iPhone 6 and iPhone 5S and test but it does not happen (I don't see it sends and receives data).

Please help me how can I connect and send data/file via Bluetooth between 2 iPhone devices in my app.

Comment: Try Multipeer Connectivity, its mildly low latency and works via bluetooth very well.

Comment: Thanks @Schemetrical. Do you have any exam source code? Please share for me, it is good for understanding

Comment: There's a lot of sample code on the internet that's very useful. I haven't done file transfers but the framework is very very promising and I've tried games with this and low latency works well. [Here's some sample code by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks Schemetrical, I try it now.